# How to write specified arguments in tcl something like -h

Tags: shell, tcl, tclsh

I am new to Tcl script, I wrote a script of an File I/O
it need users to input two kinds of strings,
one is the postfix string, one is Variable-length arguments of strings
for example i want user to run my tcl program like below

tclsh ./helloWorld.tcl -p _louis -PG vdd vcc vss

the question is how to write this in my tcl program

or basically, how to write a -help page in my program ?

i know that argv can accept the command line multiple variables, but it can not specified what i want

thank for helping

Comment: `You wrote a script` but you didn't posted it here!'

Comment: Does this one do the job? [getopt for Tcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17342)